# Accuracy of approximation to sample median

Tags: sample, median, approximation

Suppose we sample $n$ real numbers uniformly on $[a, b]$. We wish to find the sample median, but we will approximate it as follows: randomly choose a subset of the sample of size $k$ with uniform distribution and find the median of these.

How can we measure the probable accuracy of this approximation? E.g. 
"The approximation is within $m$ samples of the true median with probability .95".

Comment: This paper is hidden behind a paywall, but it may be what you want: [Approximation of the normal sample median distribution using symmetrical johnson SU distributions: application to quality control
Approximation of the normal sample median distribution using symmetrical johnson SU distributions: application to quality control (Castagliola 1998)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610919808813481)

Comment: What does it mean to be "within $m$ samples of the true median"?